# Android: set Holo Light theme for Navigation Drawer - color of listview

Tags: java, android, android-theme, navigationbar

I've downloaded the exmple "NavigationDrawer.zip" from [Google official guide](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html), Which is a basic exmple for navigation drawer.

The navigation drawer in this exmple designed as Holo dark.
My question is how do i set the navigation drawer to be Holo light?

**What I tried**

Set the background color of Holo light is easy -

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:background="#XXXX"/>
```

But

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:colorText="#XXXX"/>
```

don't work.

Comment: i've clicked enter by mystake, so the question isn't completed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if you have to, but I implemented a custom adapter that was a just a textview. By doing this I was then able to set the colour of the text that way.